# IMPORTHTML inserts line breaks

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using IMPORTHTML() to import data from my proxy-web-site, where i'm rendering a simple HTML table. And it works fine, besides the fact, that it insert line-breaks (prob. \n, not sure, but it breaks the content inside of the cell to next line) inside of the content where initially there is none of them in my source. Usually its a thing for long lines.

Why it is doing that? Is there a way to prevent it from doing that? or a fix that will replace \n for all the columns?

Here is an example document with such kind of IMPORTHTML in it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pwtVq7byD3tDT4XnSF2tUkdc-GfbQE-pDL9BSbbyQmo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML Table?

Comment: @ocordova sure, https://output.jsbin.com/nomaxiluki

Comment: The html seems ok, can you share the url to try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, IMPORTHTML added a break line character. Some alternatives to fix this are REGEXREPLACE, SUBSTITUTE among others. Example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://output.jsbin.com/nunota/quiet", "table"),CHAR(10),"")
)
```

Comment: With Substitute() using arrayformula() is necessary.  This way a non-array function can be used on arrayed data.